# How do I make random shuffle work on a list of names input by the user?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a name picker in python. First I ask the user how many names will be on the list. Then the user can input that many names. Then the list is supposed to shuffle all the names and pick one. However, every time I do this it always picks the last name that was entered by the user. How do I fix this?

#Here is my code-

## Instructions on how to use the random name picker

```
print("Hooray you decided to use a random name picker!")
print("\n")
print("Below you will be prompted on how to enter your list of names.")
print("\n")
n = int(input("How many names would you like to enter on the list today? Please press enter   after you type in your number:" +" "))
list1 =[]

for i in range(n):
names = input("Please enter the name. Press enter when finished." +" ")
list1.append(names)

print("\nHere are the names you entered into the list:",list1)

answer = input("\nAre you ready to pick a name?" +" " "Press enter to continue.")
print("\n")

import random

list1 = []
random.shuffle(list1)

print(f"The name picked: {names}")
print("\n")
```

## List after first shuffle- this part doesn't work either

```
random.shuffle(list1)
print(list1)
```

Comment: You're reassigning `list1` to an empty before shuffling. Also, if you're code is what it is, you aren't appending the names to `list1` until after the loop. So it's always going to be the last entry

Comment: I am very new to python and I am taking a college courses on teaching K-12 computer science (I am a school librarian who has taught tech classes in the past but never used python with my students as they are Kindergartens through 3rd grade). The professor for the course has yet to teach us anything but how to install python and program "Hello World" to be printed. Everything I have learned so far is from YouTube tutorials without completely understanding what I am doing.

Comment: @Wondercricket I have absolutely no clue what you mean. Sorry this is all new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While generally this site doesn't provide tutoring services, given you effort I am making an exception to help you out.

A couple of comments to begin with, random.shuffle rearranges a list of items but does not select one of the items, the better function for what you are trying to accomplish is to use the random.choice function, which returns a randomly selected item from the list.  Secondly, there is no need to ask for the number of names being entered if you use a mechanism like using the word stop to end the entry.

Now for the code which does what you want.

```
from random import choice

print("Hooray you decided to use a random name picker!\n")
print("Please enter your list of names one name at a time.")
names_list = []
while True:
    resp = input('Enter a new Name or the word quit to stop ')
    if resp.lower() == 'quit':
        break
    names_list.append(resp)
print(f"You Entered {len(names_list)} Names to include {', '.join(names_list)}" )
print(f'I have selected {choice(names_list)} at Random')
```

To try and explain what is being done.
'''names_list``` creates an empty list to hold the names to be entered.

`while True:` defines a while loop which will run forever or until a `break` is executed.

`if resp.lower == 'quit'` does a couple of things: first it uses lower to force the word stop if typed to be all lower case letters and the compares the word to the exit word 'quit' if encountered, this breaks the while loop.

`names_list.append(resp)` causes the new name to be added to the names_list.

the `print(f"You Entered {len(names_list)} Names to include {', '.join(names_list)}" )` makes use of several python functions in a single line.

1. It uses the f-string format to build a complex print statement.
2. It uses the `len(names_list)` to determine how many names were entered.
3. It uses the `', '.join(names_list)'` to convert the list into a string of names separated by a comma in order to print out how many names are in the list as well as show the full list of names.

Finally, the line `print(f'I have selected {choice(names_list)} at Random')` uses the f-string format to create a printable line which employs the random function choice to select one of the names in the list.

Hope this helps you on your way to learning python.

Comment: @itproh66   Thank you so much!!! I appreciate the time and effort you took to explain everything to me.  This has been super helpful.  Your explanations are amazing! I am trying my best to find tutorials that explain the projects the professor wants but YouTube is not the end all be all and without any guidance this class I am taking has been less than helpful. So truly, I do appreciate you making an exception to help me out.